# Modal with percentage height and min-height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to create a modal dialog whose height will be a percentage of the browser window height. The modal should have a min-height, so that it can't become impossibly small, and should grow/shrink/re-center accordingly as the window is resized. The modal has a header and a footer which sandwich the modal-body content.

Here's what I've come up with so far. If I resize the window vertically, the red box grows correctly and remains centered. However, the content area and footer don't seem to fill all the way down to the bottom of the modal container (red box).

[image]

**What's going on here and how can I fix it?**

[**- - FIDDLE HERE - -**](http://jsfiddle.net/JonMoore/d3Ym2/5/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-header">Header</div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        [...words...]
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.modal {
    border:1px solid red;
    width:600px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
}

.modal-header, .modal-body, .modal-footer {
    padding:10px;
}

.modal-header, .modal-footer {
    background:#ccc;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:14px;
}

.modal-body {
    height:inherit;
    overflow:auto;
    line-height:1.75em;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```js
$(function() {
    $('.modal').css('height','50%');
    $('.modal').css( {
        'margin-top': (-1*$('.modal').height()/2),
        'margin-left': (-1*$('.modal').width()/2)
    })
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    $('.modal').css( {
        'margin-top': (-1*$('.modal').height()/2),
        'margin-left': (-1*$('.modal').width()/2)
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kinda hacked-up, but I did it with a combination of `overflow:hidden`, `position:fixed`, several `position:absolute`s and some other random edits. This should get you going.

http://jsfiddle.net/d3Ym2/6/

Comment: Your answer is better than mine. +1

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1RJPaj97H24 , sorry, maybe I deserve to be flagged. Great name dude.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really got on this, but look [this update](http://jsfiddle.net/d3Ym2/7/).

Just set your footer with `bottom:0` and resized the height of the body.

Comment: This also works but I went ahead with @Tim's answer. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Don't worry he's answer is great!

Answer (score 0):

you do not size correctly your inside boxes .

I explain:
one of the box is set to 50% , the 2 others set to what they need. 50% left for header & footer. once it is plenty and once other not.

So set those two to 25%;

Beside , you have defaut margin on p elements, that -will jump out of the box.

Setting heigth and box-sizing to header and footer will contain them.
your CSS revisited

```
* {
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
}

.modal {
    border:1px solid red;
    width:600px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    min-height:200px;
}

.modal-header, .modal-body, .modal-footer {
    padding:10px;
    height:25%;
    box-sizing: border-box
}

.modal-header, .modal-footer {
    background:#ccc;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:14px;

}

.modal-body {
    height:inherit;
    padding:1px;
    overflow:auto;
    line-height:1.75em;
}
```

Notice, it is a good idea to set a min-height to .mobal :)